# Dynamic server baseUrl with .NET MVC and Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I was testing some SignalR with an application and everything works fine. Now to test it in the server (azurewebsites) I need to baseUrl to be dynamic and get current url so SignalR hub connection can be established.

Now I have the following code for the connection:

```js
//server configuration
export let CONFIGURATION = {
    baseUrls: {
        server: 'http://localhost:51913'
    },
}

SomeMethod()
{
this.connection = $.hubConnection(CONFIGURATION.baseUrls.server);

//... the rest of the process to connect to the hub.
}
```

Obviously this will not work with localhost as URL. How can I get the host url to start my connection? Is there any way to get it or to read it from for example WebConfig? I just don't know hot it works.

PS: Maybe there is some possibility to connect to my hub with out the specific url?

Comment: you dont know the address where you upload the app?

Comment: @GaryB there are multiple addresses, such as build, QA, etc...

Comment: I would put those into the environment and it would change accordingly

Comment: yes it is a good aproach, I will use this is the this.document.location.origin; will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get base url with below simple line of code:

```
let baseUrl = this.document.location.origin;
```

Comment: but it is suitable to use the hubConnection with this? ```this.connection = $.hubConnection(this.document.location.origin);```

Comment: Yes, try it out.

Comment: It does not work following the error: > TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Comment: I believe that this was because it was a defined in the export configuration on the component. Will try use it in the method like ```this.connection = $.hubConnection(this.document.location.origin);```

Comment: this worked if you put that in the method. thank you for help!

Comment: @Praetorian1995 Glad it worked. You may mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just if someone have the same question later on:

I would put the static addresses into the environment and it would change accordingly

Comment: Yes this is a good approach an a more elegant way to do it. Thanks for your answer!